# Hard times installing gogs.io on google container engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

As gogs.io is offering a [docker image](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/tree/master/docker), i thought it must be straight forward to install it on top of google container engine with kubernetes.

After fiddling around a few hours i got two configuration-files now, as i have seen them in an issue thread [here](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/1815):

> The files in the issue thread are using a ReplicationController instead of a pod.. and the service is also not using a LoadBalancer as type - i couldn't get it work this way neither, so i changed it to a Pod and a Service including LoadBalancer like in the wordpress tutorial of google

*gogs.yml:*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gogs
  labels:
    name: gogs
spec:
  containers:
    - name: gogs
      image: gogs/gogs
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        - containerPort: 22
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: data
    - name: postgres
      image: postgres
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgres
      env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: "gogs"
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: "gogs"
  volumes:
    - name: data
      gcePersistentDisk:
        # This disk must already exist.
        pdName: gogs-stage-data-disk
        fsType: ext4
    - name: postgres
      gcePersistentDisk:
        # This disk must already exist.
        pdName: gogs-stage-postgres-disk
        fsType: ext4
```

*gogs-service.yml:*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: gogs-frontend
  name: gogs-frontend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    # The port that this service should serve on.
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: gogs
```

Then i followed basically the steps like in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk/#wordpress_pod) to include external disks for the data and db directories.

- Create a new project, set compute zone (gcloud config set..)
- Create a new cluster `gcloud container clusters create gogs-stage --num-nodes 1`
- Create new persistent disks

`gcloud compute disks create --size 200GB gogs-stage-data-disk`

`gcloud compute disks create --size 200GB gogs-stage-postgres-disk`

- Create pod `kubectl create -f gogs.yml`
- Create the service `kubectl create -f gogs-service.yml`

Now at the point of creating the pod, it never turns from "Pending" to "Ready" also when i wait for several minutes - i check with `kubectl get pod gogs`

What is wrong with my setup? And how could i check it? I can login with ssh.. when i look there into the /var/log/messages, i can see some docker errors in the end of the file saying:

`aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[4711]: dir perm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch`

But only with that, i couldn't find anything pointing me in the right direction so far. Any help very appreciated :)

Comment: Sry for the one's who starred this question.. there seems no solution around.. right? I tried this too with gitlab without any success - postgres and redis or mysql wordpress.. all easy.. but no other packages than used in tutorials seems to work for me

Comment: FYI - gogs.io is easily installable on openshift, with this simple link: https://github.com/tkisme/gogs-openshift

Answer (score 1):

You should also specify the default data directory location using `PGDATA` environmental variable.

Try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gogs
  labels:
    name: gogs
spec:
  containers:
    - name: gogs
      image: gogs/gogs
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        - containerPort: 22
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: data
    - name: postgres
      image: postgres
      ports: 
        - containerPort: 5432
      env:
        - name : PGDATA
          value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: myuser
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: mypassword
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: mydb
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgres
  volumes:
    - name: data
      gcePersistentDisk:
        pdName: gogs-stage-data-disk
        fsType: ext4
    - name: postgres
      gcePersistentDisk:
        pdName: gogs-stage-postgres-disk
        fsType: ext4
```